# 'str' does not support the buffer interface Python 3 error for oauth

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

```
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.client import SignedJwtAssertionCredentials

json_key = json.load(open('Crowds-9569176f5988.json'))
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']

credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
#gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python\new.py", line 8, in <module>
    credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 137, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1469, in
__init__
    self.private_key = base64.b64encode(private_key)   File "C:\Python34\lib\base64.py", line 62, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1] TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

I tried encode the string using `.encode()` but `gspread.authorize()` doesn't support such a type. This is [documentation][1] which is apparently not of much help.
I am using Python 3.4. I think the documentation code works only for version before 3.

**EDIT:**

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials.from_json(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python\new.py", line 9, in 
>       credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials.from_json(json_key['client_email'],
>   json_key['private_key'], scope) TypeError: from_json() takes 2
>   positional arguments but 4 were given [Finished in 1.0s with exit code
>   1]
>
> [1]: http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials.from_json(json_key)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\sony\Desktop\Python\new.py", line 8, in 
>       credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials.from_json(json_key)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line
>   1479, in from_json
>       data = json.loads(s)   File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 312, in loads
>       s.**class**.**name**)) TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Comment: OAuth2 and spreadsheet-api with python https://github.com/asm-products/gridspree - it works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Python3.x, where `string` is not the same type as for Python 2.x. You need to cast it to bytes (encode it).

Here is simple solution that works well for me:

```
credentials = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
            json_key['client_email']
            , bytes(json_key['private_key'], 'UTF-8')
            , scope)
```

Comment: "cast" is very inaccurate. You have to `encode` strings (a sequence of unicode codepoints) into `bytes` using an encoding (a standard for how to represent codepoints as bytes)

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution in this bug report but I have not tried it myself. https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/224